# How to create an ActionDrawer with a single action

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0

as pointed out in the google guidelines: https://www.google.com/design/spec-wear/components/action-drawer.html#action-drawer-usage
at 'Single Action', an ActionDrawer should not be expandable.
My question is, how to achieve that behaviour?
I've tried an `WearableActionDrawer` and `WearableDrawerView`..
I've also tried the method `lockDrawerClosed()` but the drawer still opens on click.
Thanks for your help! :)

Edit:
Ok, I found the solution to stop the drawer from opening. I'm using the `WearableActionDrawer` now and calling `lockDrawerClosed()`. But now I'm not sure how to change the peek_view properly.

I made a custom view - LinearLayout - which is containing an ImageView. I'm using this view for `mWearableActiondrawer.setPeekView(myView)`. But the problem is, that the view will not be shown properly. It just shows me an empty ActionDrawer at the bottom.
But the clicklistener is working..

Here is my code:

```
// Bottom Action Drawer
mWearableActionDrawer = (WearableActionDrawer) findViewById(R.id.bottom_action_drawer);
mWearableActionDrawer.lockDrawerClosed();

LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
    (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout view =
    (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.action_drawer_peek_view, null);

mWearableActionDrawer.setPeekContent(view);

view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Layout:

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_drawer_peek_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/wearable_primary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:src="@drawable/fill_1_copy"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any thoughts of what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any error as compared to this [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearDrawers/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/weardrawers/MainActivity.java). It stated that if you only have a single action for your Action Drawer, you can use a (custom) `View` to peek on top of the content by calling `mWearableActionDrawer.setPeekContent(View)`. Just make sure you set a click listener to handle user clicking on your `View`.

You may also try using `mWearableDrawerLayout.peekDrawer(Gravity.BOTTOM);`. Check again your implementation based on this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/ui-nav-actions.html#initialize) which shows how to initialize the contents of your drawers.